# Creating a 3x3 grid with constraints

Tags: r, sudoku

The aim is to have R automatically solve the 3x3 grid problem below.

There is a 3x3 grid with elements:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

The letters a to i can only be the integers 1 to 9 and each integer much be used only once in the grid(for example a=1, b=2, c=3,...,h=8 and i=9. 
In addition to this, there are 4 smaller 2 x 2 grids within the grid above:

```
a b         b c            d e       e f
d e         e f            g h       h i
```

The sum of all elements in these 2x2 grids are equal to some number (In this instance it is a+b+d+e=20, b+c+e+f=17,d+e+g+h=27 and e+f+h+i=15).

I am trying to right some code to solve this problem on R using the linear programming tool.

My thought process was to create constraints such that only integers are used (9 constraints), each integer can  only be used once (9 constraints) and the 4 2x2 grid constraints but after a bit of deliberation, i may have gone down completely the wrong path. If anyone could show and point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

Comment: Integer programming problem? Note that 'e' is in all of those equations and might be useful to rearrange: a+b+d-20 = -e, b+c+f-17= -e, d+g+h-27 =-e and f+h+i-15 = -e. Then a+b+d-20 =b+c+f-17 and d+g+h-27 = f+h+i-15, and a couple of other left side combos. Might even turn into a nice 4 x4 matrix to be solved.

Comment: Thank you, that help and I think i know what to do now